# How get properties from object named '0'

Tags: php, object, properties

I have that code

```
$names=array('name1'=>'John','Bill');
$names = (object)$names;
```

If I want get name John, I do :

```
$names->name1;
```

But, How can I get name 'Bill' ?

Comment: Actually, curly braces doesn't save the situation: `Undefined property: stdClass::$0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a issue/bug. [ https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45959 ]

It's best to avoid array-to-object casts & If you really need to do, Create a new instance of stdClass and then manually renaming the variable. (Not a right Solution & I'm sure You must be knowing this!)

```
<?php
$names=array('name1'=>'John','Bill');
$obj = new stdClass;
foreach ($names as $k => $v) {
    if (is_numeric($k)) {
        $k = "_{$k}";
    }
    $obj->$k = $v;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
echo "</pre>";

echo $obj->_0;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`First way`

```
$names=array('name1'=>'John','name2'=>'Bill');
$names = (object)$names;

var_dump($names->name2);//Bill
```

Second way:
using the loop get all variables:

```
$names=array('name1'=>'John','Bill');
$names = (object)$names;
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo ($name);
}
```

Comment: I don't want change the key.
$names->{'0'}
That doesn't work, because it returns NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
list($names->name1,$names->name2)=array_values(array('name1'=>'John','Bill'));
echo $names->name2; // Bill
```

**EDIT1**

```
$names=array('name1'=>'John','Bill');
$names = (object)$names;

echo end($names); // Bill
```

**EDIT2**

```
$names=array('name1'=>'John','Bill');
$names = (object)$names;

echo next($names); // Bill
```

Comment: @Paweł Brzoski  look at answer

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through it:

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
    var_dump($name);
}
```

output:

```
string 'John' (length=4)

string 'Bill' (length=4)
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want use loop